# How to open new tab, wait for tab to load, then redirect that same tab?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, registerstartupscript

I am using ASP.NET with say, OpenLink.aspx and OpenLink.aspx.cs

I have a link in the page that should, when clicked, open a new tab on a different website (that shares our user base exactly). This page must first be logged in to.

I first tried doing this in OpenLink.aspx:

```
<a href="tgt.com/page" id="mylink" runat="server" target="_Blank">Go to Page</a>
```

The problem with this is that one must first login to access tgt.com, so this only works if they have already been on this site recently on the same browser. But I do have all the necessary info to login them in. So I then tried in OpenLink.aspx.cs:

```
protected void mylink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string loginScript = "<script>window.open('tgt.com/login.aspx?email=......','mynewtab');</script>"
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "openWindow", loginScript);
    string destScript = "<script>window.open('tgt.com/page','mynewtab');</script>"
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "openWindow", destScript);
}
```

In this case only the top one runs. I would try to just wait some time between the commands, but it doesn't seem like RegisterStartupScript executes the script immediately (my knowledge of that stuff isn't great), and anyway when I tried Thread.Sleep(3000), I got all of these "asynchronous operations are not allowed" errors.

Any Ideas

Comment: You would in theory have to put the logon code in the target page, not the source page. So in that page that loads on the tab, that's the page that needs to login the user. and your injecting 2 JavaScript routines, but give them both the same name - hence only one is going to run. So another idea would be to change the name of your 2nd injected script. and I do suggest you use "true" for the last parameter to surround your js code with script tags, and thus not have to include that in your injected js code.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Thanks for the input. Unfortunately I am unable to edit the target page's code--at least not for this release.

Comment: Hum, as noted, you need to give both injected scripts a different name, or better yet try combing the js code into one code block you inject. I not 100% sure if your injection can work, but 2 separate js injections means you don't have much control when one runs, and the other is finished.